# What happens when I run out of Strike Teams?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

If I use all my Strike teams on a tactical strike map, is that it, can I no longer play those maps until I start a new campaign?  Will I no longer be able to play any tactical strike maps until I get new strike teams?  For that matter, when do I get more strike teams?

Comment: Can you please clarify 'strike teams'?

Comment: @Meraj99 There is a counter indicating the amount of Strike teams you have left when selecting a tactical strike map in the campaign. This number decreases if you fail to complete a tactical strike map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three strikes and you're out.
If you get what I mean...

Anyways, you get more strike force missions as you go further into the story.
The campaign does continue on but the success/failure of the strike force will affect the rest of the story. As in, you get new strike teams for later strike force missions.

The Strike Force missions include:

[FOB Spectre](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/FOB_Spectre)

[Shipwreck](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Shipwreck)

[I.E.D.](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/I.E.D)

[Second Chance](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Chance_%28Strike_Force%29)

[Dispatch](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Dispatch)

[Strike Force Training](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Strike_Force_Training)

[missions from Call of Duty wikia]